# Saving a dataset with ImagingCore objects pickle

Tags: python, json, dataset, pickle

I have created a dataset mapping images to their labels for a ml project. I want to save the dataset on a script and load it in another one to save time every time I rerun the code for the model.
The output from the dataset gives me a list of tuples containing an ImagingCore object and 2 string type objects.
The output of `print(dataset)` is

```
[(<ImagingCore object at 0x12091a825>, 'R', 'FIRST'),(<ImagingCore object at 0x12091a850>, 'L', 'THIRD'),...]
```

Where the second element of each tuple is either left or right, and the third goes from first to fourth.

I have tried to save the dataset with pickle, json, dill, hickle, using the structure

```
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
     pickle.dump(dataset, f)
```

but I always get the same error:

> TypeError: cannot pickle 'ImagingCore' object

Can someone help? This has been literally driving me crazy for weeks

Comment: Please share your code/data structure.

Comment: @TenaciousB I have added my code and the dataset output

Answer (score 0):

That error tells me PIL's objects aren't pickleable. They're native objects (likley C instead of python code), so it makes sense that they don't automatically support pickling. You could either **pickle a different set of data** (a proxy object) or use a **custom Pickler** to support pickling their data.

See the [Pickleable Image Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118068/pickleable-image-object) question for how to pull data out of `PIL.Image` that *can* be pickled.

[Persistence of External Objects in the `pickle` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#persistence-of-external-objects) shows how to write your own pickler. Looks like the code should be something like this (untested):

```
import pickle
from PIL import Image  # Assuming Pillow
from collections import namedtuple

# Proxy the PIL.Image by storing the bytes.
ImageProxy = namedtuple("ImageProxy", "pixels, size, mode")


class PilPickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def persistent_id(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Image):
            # Create our proxy that (I think) will get pickled in lieu of a PIL object.
            return ImageProxy(
                pixels=obj.tobytes(),
                size=obj.size,
                mode=obj.mode,
            )
        else:
            # Fallback to default pickle.
            return None


class PilUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def persistent_load(self, pid):
        # pid is the object returned by PilPickler.
        if isinstance(pid, ImageProxy):
            return Image.frombytes(pid.mode, pid.size, pid.pixels)
        else:
            # Always raise an error if you cannot return the correct object.
            raise pickle.UnpicklingError("unsupported persistent object")


def main():
    import io
    import pprint

    images = []  # [... make images here ...]

    # Save the records using our custom PilPickler.
    file = io.BytesIO()
    PilPickler(file).dump(images)

    print("Pickled records:")
    pprint.pprint(images)

    # Load the records from the pickle data stream.
    file.seek(0)
    images = PilUnpickler(file).load()

    print("Unpickled records:")
    pprint.pprint(images)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think your `ImagingCore` are the native part of `PIL.Image`, so this custom Pickler solution allows you to keep your existing setup and any `PIL.Image`s inside your data structures will get pickled. If you are using other `PIL` objects, you may need to add support for them with more `isinstance` checks and proxy objects.